# Read data from a JSON file

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file out of the custom JSON pattern. And I need get this string values with array, list or anything.

example.json:

```
[
   ["fight", "gunshot", "fleeing"], 
   ["gunshot", "falling", "fleeing"] 
]
```

Comment: You can use Newtonsoft.Json package. [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: you don't have any ideas? what did you try for this?

Comment: also this is not a json..

Comment: The input is more like array of string array and what is the expected output?

Comment: @godot  Yes, it is. It's a `List<List<string>>`, or similar.

Comment: @godot it is stored in .json I need solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use @Jimi option like that

First

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Then

```
string myJsonString = @"[['fight', 'gunshot', 'fleeing'], ['gunshot', 'falling', 'fleeing']]";
List<List<string>> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(myJsonString );

Console.Write(items[0][0]);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    foreach(var subitem in item){
        Console.WriteLine(subitem);
    }
}
```

also here is working version this code maybe you can create a simular stack app then share with us.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/oKUUxa